# Cakephp creates many cache files

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cakephp

I've just started writing code with this framework. I have a big problem after adding this code to my View file (to add AJAX support for the form):

```
echo $this->Js->submit('Send',array( 
'before'=> $this->Js->get('#success')->effect('fadeOut'),
'success'=>$this->Js->get('#success')->effect('fadeIn'),
'update'=>'#success'
));
```

Every time I refresh the page, Cakephp creates a file named {hash}.js like 987276be3fa726db322142ee6dfee435.js What's more, every refresh takes around 5s. 
So after a few hours of work I had over 200 files in /webroot/js.
Every file contains code like this:

`$(document).ready(function () {$("#submit-1856995147").bind("click", function (event) {$.ajax({beforeSend:function (XMLHttpRequest) {$("#success").fadeOut();}, data:$("#submit-1856995147").closest("form").serialize(), dataType:"html", success:function (data, textStatus) {$("#success").fadeIn();$("#success").html(data);}, type:"post", url:"\/newapp\/Sender"});
    return false;});});`

Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: did your disable cache in AppController...?

Comment: But disabling cache in AppController for ex. by adding Controller::disableCache(); tells only the user's browser not to cache data - Cakephp is caching JS on Server side and i want to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

try

core.php(inside /app/config/) has lot of features that help us improve our web application.

```
Configure::write(‘Asset.timestamp’, ‘force’);
```

This will helpful for you.

Comment: Unfortunately cakephp still creates those files and first AJAX request takes around 5 sec